# Server Json Response my be invalid for JSONObject on android

Tags: java, php, android, json

i am trying to make a login on android using loopj asynctask to link to database but i have issues. it Seems like the JSONObject is not working. Help me check if i am making a mistake. Here is my code

```
package com.truparsecreative.uimobile;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class login extends ActionBarActivity {
public EditText username, password;
public Button login_button;
ProgressDialog progress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    //login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);


    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setMessage("Connecting...");
    progress.setCancelable(false);
}

public void loginUser(View view) {
    String user = username.getText().toString();
    String pass = password.getText().toString();

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    if (user != "" && pass != "") {
        params.put("username", user);
        params.put("password", pass);
        invokeWS(params);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Matric and Password cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void invokeWS(RequestParams params) {
    progress.show();
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.post("http://10.0.2.2/uimobile/app/android/login.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String content) {
            super.onSuccess(content);
            progress.hide();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
                String mat = jsonObject.getString("matric");
                if (mat !=null)
                {
                    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), profile.class);
                    loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(loginIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,String content) {
            //super.onFailure(error, content);
                progress.hide();
                if (statusCode == 404) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (statusCode == 500) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```

and the login.php code is

```
<?php require_once('connect.php'); 
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$c_login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE matric = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
if (mysql_num_rows($c_login)>0)
{
    echo "Correct Details";
    //$output = array();
    $content = mysql_fetch_array($c_login);
    $output = array(
        'matric'=> $content['matric'],
        'password'=> $content['password'],
        'email'=> $content['email']
        );
    print json_encode($output);
}
else
{
     echo "Username and password didn't match".mysql_error();
}

?>
```

Comment: Neither "I have issues" nor "it seems like the JSONObject is not working" are very clear problem statements. What exactly is the problem you are facing? Do you get an error? If so, show us the error. Do you get unexpected behavior? If so, describe the behavior. In any case, edit your question to clarify what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code you are doing this before you send the JSON object:

```
echo "Correct Details";
```

Because of that line your PHP code doesn't send a valid JSON object to the Android application.
The result from the PHP script will have this format:

```
Correct Details
{
  matric: "some value",
  password: "some value",
  email: "some value"
}
```

Which isn't a valid JSON object because of the first line `Correct Details` produced by `echo "Correct Details";`